# Difficulty creating @TypeConverter from third-party object

Tags: android, database, android-room

I try to insert an object  from a third-party class to an room table, the problem is that i got this exaption:

```
  RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface
  org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.ExtensionElement. Registering an
  InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

I understand that Gson can't convert object from third-party class, how can I do it well anyway?

I tried to create InstanceCreator but I get the same error (maybe I'm not creating it correctly), this is the TypeConverter class:

```
@TypeConverter
public String stringFromObject(Message message){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(message);
}

@TypeConverter
public Message getObjectFromString(String jsonString){
    Type listType = new TypeToken<Message>(){}.getType();
    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, listType);
}
```

Comment: I suspect that the real problem is: you should not be attempting to save an `ExtensionElement` to persistent storage. Regardless, `ExtensionElement` is an interface; nothing (including Gson) can create an instance of `ExtensionElement` directly.

Comment: thank you, so what can i do here instead @CommonsWare

Comment: Get your data out of the message and save the data, not the Smack wrapper objects.